# How to open only a .dat file. In C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to open a file but I want it filter out to only .dat file.

```
using (OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
    fileName = fileChooser.FileName; //Get file name.
    fileChooser.Filter = "Data File|*.dat;";
    fileChooser.DefaultExt = "dat";
    fileChooser.AddExtension = true;
}
```

When having a OpenFileDialog in "using" the filter, defaultExt and Addextension doesn't work.

Comment: `;";` should be `";` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8 may be worth a read for a more thorough example (if you are using WPF). See my below link if you are using Winforms.

Comment: Shouldn't be the ShowDialog() the last thing to call?

Comment: `defaultExt and Addextension doesn't work.` The code you have copied is for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8 (WPF). You are likely using Winforms (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 3):

You should set filters before the call of "ShowDialog" method.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
using (var fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    // define the filters (first description | first filter; second description ...
    fileChooser.Filter = "Data File|*.dat";
    // select the first filter
    fileChooser.FilterIndex = 1;
    fileChooser.DefaultExt = "dat";
    fileChooser.AddExtension = true;

    // show the Opendialog
    if (fileChooser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // get the path of specified file
        var filename = fileChooser.FileName;

        // use the filename to open the file...
    }
}
```